# VBA: String array doesn't export when unloading userform

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft365

I'm writing a VBA code where I need a userform to return a couple of string arrays with file names. The arrays are set like this in the main module:

```
Public [...] defs, prer_list(), sum_list(), other_list() [...] As String
```

The userform is a bunch of checkboxes and I want the checked ones to be sorted into the different arrays. This works perfectly as long as the userform is open, but when it unloads I loose all data. What am I doing wrong?

Code in userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim n As Integer, _
obj As Control

n = 0
ReDim prer_list(0)
ReDim sum_list(0)
ReDim other_list(0)


For Each obj In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(obj) = "CheckBox" Then
        If obj.Value = True Then
            If obj.Caption Like "*type1*" Then
                ReDim Preserve prer_list(UBound(prer_list) + 1)
                prer_list(UBound(prer_list)) = obj.Caption
                
            ElseIf obj.Caption Like "*type2*" Then
                ReDim Preserve sum_list(UBound(sum_list) + 1)
                sum_list(UBound(sum_list)) = obj.Caption
                
            ElseIf obj.Caption Like "*Definitions*" Then
                defs = obj.Caption
                
            Else
                ReDim Preserve other_list(UBound(other_list) + 1)
                other_list(UBound(other_list)) = obj.Caption
            End If
                
        End If
        
    End If
Next
   
Unload Me

End Sub
```

I've got no idea what I missed.

Edited to add: It seems the arrays are still intact inside the userform if I go back to it during the same session, they just doesn't export to the main module that I use to show the userform

Comment: Public variables only work in a standard module. Declare those in a standard module, not the userform. See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables#public-statement

Comment: Might give [this](https://rubberduckvba.blog/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) a read for why `Unload Me` is preferably avoided.

Comment: @tigeravatar the public variables are set in the main/standard module

Comment: @BigBen Interesting read! However it doesn't seem to matter whether I hide or unload the form. While in the form I can see that my string arrays have values, both before and after unloading/hiding. It's when I end the sub and go back to the main code that I loose the data. If I reaccess the userform the arrays' data is still there in both cases. It just never exports out into the main module.

Comment: Do you have extra declarations (`Dim`-statements) for the variables in the Userform? In your CommandButton1_Click-routine, place the cursor on one of the variables and press Shift+F2: Does it jump to the variable definition of your main module?

Comment: @FunThomas that's a neat trick! but yes, it does jump to the main module. The code does work now however, although I can't say what I've done differently.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had an annoying but simple solution. In my main module I made a misstake in how to access the content of the arrays. When it didn't work I added the arrays to the watch to check that they were created correctly.

Apparently, the watch stops working when you move back to the module window, and you need to create a new one for that window. Baam, arrays found, mistake found, and the issue solved.